# How to create breadcrumb shape

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I've been trying to create a breadcrumb in the shape of an arrow that has a point on one end and a tail at the other.

Basically, the layout is:  [tail][body][point], where tail & point are just triangles.

I managed to create [body][point] using css, but i'm stuck trying to make the tail to work. Can this also be done with css?

DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/mQELiNgVCe6ZoTepCtr9?p=preview

The HTML:

```
<div style="font-size:0">
    <div class="arrow-tail"></div>
    <div class="arrow-body">HELLO WORLD!</div>
    <div class="arrow-point"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    .arrow-point {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid #777777;
}
.arrow-body {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size:15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #777777;
    color:white;
    padding:2px 6px 2px 16px;
    height:20px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.arrow-tail {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid #EEEEEE;
}
```

Comment: not enough info. I see what looks like a triangle at the end of your breadcrumb. can you provide an image as to what it should look like or give more detail on what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bit difficult to understand how you want the final result to look like based on the information you provided in the original post. But I make some guesses and I believe that you want it to look like this:

[image]

You can achieve this by setting the tail to `position: absolute`.

The final CSS of the tail would be this:

```
.arrow-tail {
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid #fff;
}
```

Also note that if you want to move around your tail with the `top:`, `right:`, `bottom:`, `left:` attributes then you need to make sure that the container div is set to `position: relative`.